# How to map multiple parents to single child record

Tags: sql, sql-server

First, let me describe the business problem:

Each time a Sales Rep makes a call, he must make a record of what happened in the call.  This is called a disposition.  But some dispositions can have child dispositions - meaning if they selected that one, then they get a further list of items to select.  And some of those also have child dispositions to those. (Max 3 levels).

The business requirement is then to not only capture the final disposition selected, but also the intermediate ones.

How do I model this in the database?

So far, we have come up with a Disposition_Map table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dispo_map](
    [dispo_map_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [parent_dispo_id] [int] NULL,
    [child_dispo_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [dispo_map_type_id] [int] NOT NULL,
```

This does actually work, but it seems convoluted to me.

Comment: Why not simply have a ParentDispo column in your Disposition table?

Comment: YOu seem to be thinking to wrong way round. Don't map parents to children, map children to Parents. As @GuillaumeCR suggested you want a Parent ID column; you don't need a child ID column as that can be inferred by the Parent Child relationhip from the parent ID column

Comment: You should look at CTEs - don't rate any of the answers given so far. See
https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/04/24/sql-server-introduction-to-hierarchical-query-using-a-recursive-cte-a-primer/ - You can add level for depth in hierarchy too. You can easily go to any level of depth this way,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating on the correct comments, here is one basic setup using a foreign key. Thus, when you insert a record into `dispo_map`, it must contain the `parent_dispo_id` which is mapped to `dispo.dispo_id`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dispo](
    [dispo_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [dispo_map_type_id] [int] NOT NULL)

ALTER TABLE dbo.dispo
add constraint PK_dispo_id primary key(dispo_id)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dispo_map](
    [dispo_map_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [parent_dispo_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [dispo_map_type_id] [int] NOT NULL)

ALTER TABLE dbo.dispo_map
add constraint PK_dispo_map_id primary key(dispo_map_id)

ALTER TABLE dbo.dispo_map
add constraint FK_parent_dispo foreign key(parent_dispo_id) references dispo(dispo_id)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was thinking along these lines as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Foreign keys to get this done!

A Foreign Key is a value on the table which links directly to a unique value either in the same table or a different table. So, a foreign key would be the reference between your different dispositions.

For example, let's say your sales call table looks like this:

[int,PK Sales Call ID], [int Employee ID], [varchar Disposition]

So, each sale call has an ID, and an associated employee ID to indicate who made the call. It also has a 'root' disposition, that first layer you're talking about. But then what about a child disposition? Well, that could look something like this:

[int,PK Disposition ID], [int,FK Sales Call ID], [varchar Disposition]

Notice how in our disposition table the Sales Call ID has an FK constraint? That means that it associates directly to a Sales Call ID in the previous table. And if you wanted to have a child-child disposition, that could look something like this:

[int,PK Disposition ID], [int, FK Parent Disposition ID], [varchar Disposition]

Each *type* of disposition gets a table, and each *association* gets a Foreign key constraint. That way, you can't add dispositions which don't associate either to calls or other dispositions, and you can always figure out who the disposition belongs to by following the chain of foreign keys.

Check these MSDN Docs for syntax on foreign key relationships in T-SQL, if that's what you're using:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-2017

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve *most* of your requirements by using a self-referencing FK. In this case, your disposition table needs an FK to its own PK, in a column presumably named parent_dispo_id.

The requirement that is not satisfied with this approach is the maximum depth, which you would need to enforce at the application layer. To be fair, your suggested approach also does not enforce the 3 levels of max nesting. In order to enforce this at the database layer, I guess you would need to use your mapping table, but you would need to have the parent dispo, the child dispo and a nullable grandchild dispo in the same table, with a unique constraint on the 3 columns.